# Выгрузка всех данных о пользователях и заказах

Tags: php, mysql, woocommerce

Нужно сделать выгрузку всех данных всех пользователей в `woocommerce`, т.е. собрать в массив и потом уже использовать данный массив к примеру для создания `csv`. 
А именно нужны такие поля:
`user_id, first_name, last_name, email, phone, order_ids, total, discount, product_ids`

`order_ids` - `order_id` всех заказов у текущего пользователя, нужно перечислить через запятую,
`total` - общая сумма, которую пользователь заплатил за товары,
`discount` - общая сумма скидок, к примеру по купонам,
`product_ids` - `product_id` всех товаров, которые пользователь купил, через запятую
т.е. в каждом ряду должна быть информация по отдельному пользователю.

Интересует такой вопрос:
подходит ли данный код для этой задачи?

```
$order_statuses = array('wc-completed');
$users = array();
$all_users = get_users();
foreach($all_users as $user){
    $_user = array();
    $order_ids = array();
    $total = array();
    $discount = array();
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value' => $user->ID,
        'post_status' => $order_statuses,
        'numberposts' => -1,
    ) );
    foreach($customer_orders as $order){
        $order_ids[] = $order->get_id();
        $total[] = $order->get_total();
    }
    $_user['email'] = $user->user_emal;
    ...
    $users[] = $_user;
}
```

получается для каждого отдельного пользователя вызывается отдельный цикл по заказам, ведь пользователей может быть тысячи.
Есть ли вариант чтобы как-то оптимизировать данную задачу?
Может быть с помощью `wpdb` и `sql`-запросов.
И пользователи могут не иметь заказов, к примеру подписчики.

**P.S.**
таблицы, отвечающие за пользователей:
`users:   user_id,user_email,user_pass,user_login`
`usermeta: в этой таблице дополнительные поля пользователей(не обязательна)`
таблицы, связанные с заказоми:
`posts: ID,post_title,post_status`
`postmeta: дополнительные поля заказов (второстепенная таблица с дополнительными. данными)`
`woocommerce_order_items: тут номер заказа и ссылка на таблицу с купленными товарами`
`woocommerce_order_itemmeta: тут список купленных товаров, данные товары привязаны к таблице woocommerce_order_items`

Comment: Прямой `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE`. Если, конечно, доступен. Если нет- ну просто SELECT сразу всех нужных данных одним запросом, и сброс в файл..

Comment: @Akina, я спрашиваю про оптимизацию

Comment: Нет лучшей оптимизации чем избавление от итераций. Оба предложенных мной метода именно это и делают.

Comment: @Akina, т.е. лучше использовать один запрос для выбора всех пользователей вместе с их заказами?

Comment: Ну во всяком случае это будет гораздо быстрее.

Comment: а как это сделать правильно?
нужны подзапросы?

Comment: `select * from users where user_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...10000)` или `select * from users`

Comment: а как выбрать заказы этих пользователей в одном запросе?

Comment: А вот чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, нужно: 1) структуру всех таблиц (CREATE TABLE) 2) Пример данных (INSERT INTO, 3-5 записей основной таблицы и столько же в связанной для каждой основной записи). 3) Желаемый результат на именно таких данных (полностью). И - это в общем уже будет несколько другой вопрос, так что нет смысла исправлять этот, лучше создать новый.

Comment: INSERT INTO не нужен, главное собрать в массив

Comment: SELECT - он даст набор записей, фактически плоскую таблицу, которую PHP при получении интерпретирует как ассоциативный массив (если не тащить по одной записи). Но вопрос получения данных в MySQL и вопрос интерпретации результата в PHP - это два совсем разных вопроса. С нерешённым первым нет смысла браться за второй.

Comment: @Akina а можете скинуть примерный запрос? 
или создавать новую тему? 
дополнил вопрос

Comment: Лучше создайте новую тему - и с именно указанной информацией, а не с "сочинением по мотивам".

Comment: @Akina, подскажите пожалуйста, 
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1094245/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2